# ScrollView can't show the last element

Tags: android, xml

I'm making a simple layout in android studio like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context="hisoka.poipo.com.wishtleblower.KorupsiActivity"
    android:scrollIndicators="right"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#F0FFFF"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomMargin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Keterangan :"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:ems="10"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:id="@+id/ket_et" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#B0E0E6"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomMargin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightMargin"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Terduga :"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="Nama :"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 />
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="Jabatan :"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 />
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                />

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Klasifikasi Jabatan :"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/korupsiSpinnera"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="Nama :"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="4dip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    />
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:text="Jabatan :"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_margin="4dip"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    />
            <EditText
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/box"
                android:layout_margin="4dip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                />

                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Klasifikasi Jabatan :"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:layout_margin="4dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    />
                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/korupsiSpinnerb"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
         </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#B0E0E6"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"

        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightMargin"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Lampiran :"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Nama File "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Rfounder "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Keterangan "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="CEO "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Size "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="36 KB "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Delete "
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="X"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Add File"
            />
        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#B0E0E6"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/topMargin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/bottomMargin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftMargin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/rightMargin"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Kirim Laporan"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Captcha"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/box"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:ems="7"
            />
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New CheckBox"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

In android studio, I can see that last element right there as shown below :
[image: preview in android studio]
But When I run it on my real device, the last element can't be shown, my last button is missing :
[image: real device]
I have goggled some pages and said that just add

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

to scrolView. but this doesn't solve my problem.... I have added another xml tag but still nothing...

Comment: Try removing android:layout_gravity=end i think its not nescessary

Comment: Try to give padding to scrollview to bottom ...

Comment: I need that layout_gravity=end Mr. Jois... :)

Comment: Okieee Mr.Er. Arjun Saini... gimme a moment... :)

Comment: Try some padding bottom in the scrollview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for suggestion from Mr. Er. Arjun, I finally got the answer... I put this

```
android:paddingBottom="57dp"
```

to scrollview... and it's fixed... :)

[image]

Comment: Even though its a hack... After searching for 1 hour Its the only thing that worked for me :P

Comment: To add to my previous comment: In my case I added paddingBottom of just "1dp" to the scrollView (with fillViewport=true) and my problem got solved on all size emulators :)

Answer (score 3):

I think your using `AppbarLayout` if so then you should use `NestedScrollView`

just replace your `ScrollView` with this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Comment: Ooowh...mmmm... I havent' tried NestedScrollView... but thanks for your answer mr. Anders... :)

Comment: your welcome, adding padding to bottom is not a proper solution just a hack, to add extra space to bottom so the space would lift your buttons up